# OpenCL - CL_INVALID_VALUE while reading from Buffer

Tags: c++, opencl

because of the code is rather long, so i try to post what is important.

I allocated an array, create the buffer, pass to kernel like this.

```
cl_mem correspondenceRes= NULL;
int size_correspondence_result = model_voxelized->size()*3*num_angle_steps*num_shift_steps;
float* correspondence_result = new float[size_correspondence_result];
correspondenceRes = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(size_correspondence_result),correspondence_result,&ret);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel,6,sizeof(correspondenceRes), &correspondenceRes);
```

And later on read it back from buffer :

```
ret =  clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue,correspondenceRes,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(correspondence_result), &correspondence_result[0],0,NULL,NULL);
```

Then i got the code -30, speak CL_INVALID_VALUE, also could mean that I put the wrong size of the object in ClEnqueueReadBuffer. Meanwhile for another argument, I created and read like this :

```
cl_mem corr_result = NULL;
cl_int* corr_result_count = new cl_int[prod];
corr_result= clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(corr_result_count),corr_result_count,&ret);
ret=clSetKernelArg(kernel,7,sizeof(corr_result),&corr_result);
```

An later on read it from Buffer with this :

```
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue,corr_result,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(corr_result_count), &corr_result_count[0],0,NULL,NULL);
```

And the reading part works perfectly, **BUT** the values inside the array is not what i expected (All random numbers, unless my kernel code define it explicitly).

Note that I do not do any calculation inside kernel, just pass and read it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first issue, you are using the wrong size when creating your buffer.  `sizeof(size_correspondence_result)` should be `sizeof(float) * size_correspondence_result`, otherwise it's equivalent to `sizeof(int)`.  You need to use this same size when reading it back, as well.  I strongly suggest you read up on [how sizeof() works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) so you understand what value it's returning.

As for the second issue, you are allocating memory, and then immediately creating a buffer with `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`, which copies your uninitialized memory into the buffer.  There should be no reason to do this; either initialize the memory first, or if you only want uninitialized memory for write/read on the device itself, don't use `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` (and assume the memory is uninitialized in your kernel).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check with the first issue. But about the second, which flag should i use instead ? Because if i remove it it will show code -37.

I know that the array is uninitialized, meaning it will have 0 values (default). Should i use CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR flag in this case instead ?

Comment: Uninitialized does **not** mean zeroed, it means it could be anything.  To zero initialize your array you'd have to allocate it like this: `new float[size_correspondence_result]()`.  Alternatively you could use memset() or ZeroMemory(), the latter being specific to the Windows API.

Comment: Hi, so does it mean i got the -37 code because my array is not initialized, only allocated ? Or the code shows that my Buffer Object is not allocated (in this case still NULL) ? Thanks for your answers !

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you are supposed to allocate uninitialized memory on a device.  I assume by default (i.e. not putting any flags) it would do so, but I can't find any verification of this in the spec.  `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` is supposed to allocate memory on the **host** for you, though it's not clear for what purpose (but presumably for a later clEnqueueReadBuffer() or clEnqueueWriteBuffer() call).